# android fixed layout size when listview visibility is gone

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Is there any way to set the layout height and width fixed,even inside element visibility:gone ?

I have 2 listviews.when the app starts those are in

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

state.Then its become visible when a button click.But layout is re-sized when they are showing.(these layouts are run as DialogFragments). How to stop this re-sizing and giving a fixed width and height to the layout.

here is my layout file

```
        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:minWidth="500dp"
         android:minHeight="600dp"

android:background="#ffffff"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"> 

      <Button
            android:id="@+id/cus_add_cancel_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button_border"
            android:text="Cancel" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/pagerow"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="Add Customer"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/cus_add_save_btn"

          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/menu_button_border"
          android:text="Save"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:textColor="@color/White" />

</TableRow>   






      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
             <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tablseRoere"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/tesxtViewere"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="2dp"

                  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/redbar_separator"               
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                   />
          </TableRow>

             <TableRow
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              >

                <Button
            android:id="@+id/cus_add_window_btn"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

             android:textColor="@color/Red"
                  android:background="@drawable/button_border_clicked"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:gravity="center"


            android:text="Add New" />

              <Button
            android:id="@+id/cus_search_btn"
                 android:layout_width="160dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:textColor="@color/White"
                  android:background="@drawable/button_border_right"

          android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Search" />

          </TableRow>

         <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRoeeeree"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewrerere"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="2dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/redbar_separator"               
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                   />
          </TableRow>



          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/search_window_item1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/cus_searchtxt"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
                  android:ems="10"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:hint="Search Customer"
                  android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/TextVijewgh"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                  android:text="C-D" />
          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
               android:id="@+id/search_window_item2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >





             <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/cus_list"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                   android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="left"
                   />






                  <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/pages"
                     android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="300dp"
                   android:visibility="gone"
                    android:gravity="right"
                   />


          </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >



              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fn"
             android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


               <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ln"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s1"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="A-B" />

          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >




               <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_fnametxt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
            android:hint="First Name" />


              <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s10"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    />

                <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_lnametxt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s2"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="C-D" />

          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item3"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >



              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/srt"
             android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Street"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


               <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lsn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s3"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="E-F" />

          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item4"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >




               <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_streettxt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
            android:hint="Street" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s4"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="G-H" />

          </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item5"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >



              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dn"
             android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Door No"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


               <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text="City"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s5"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="I-J" />

          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item6"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >




               <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_doortxt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
            android:hint="Door No" />

               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s1s0"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    />


                <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_citytxtt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
            android:hint="City" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s6"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="K-L" />

          </TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item7"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >



              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pc"
             android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Postal Code"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


               <TextView
            android:id="@+id/em"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s7"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="M-N" />

          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item8"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >




               <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_postalcodetxt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
            android:hint="Postal Code" />

               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sss10"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    />


                <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_emailtxt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
            android:hint="Email" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s8"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="O-P" />

          </TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item9"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >



              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phn"
             android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Contact Number"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


               <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lssn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="left"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s9"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="Q-T" />

          </TableRow>

          <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/addnew_window_item10"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" >




               <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_contactno_txt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/lost_focus_style"
             android:inputType="phone" 
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:hint="Contact Number" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ss10"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="U-Z" />

          </TableRow>



      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use android:layout_weight, try the link for more info.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Comment: i have used android:layout_weight inside TableRow. but i dont know how to use it outside TableRow

Comment: Check the answer is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.At the starting place two dummy view and enable and disable the views according to your need.At the starting make the `list visibility = "gone"` and  `view visibility = "visible"` .And reverse it on button click.

```
<TableRow
               android:id="@+id/search_window_item2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="1">

             <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/cus_list"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                   />
             <View 
                 android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
                  <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/pages"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="300dp"
                   android:layout_weight=".5"
                   android:visibility="gone"
                   android:layout_gravity="right"
                   />
                  <View 
                 android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"/>


          </TableRow>
```

Comment: Still its re sizing the Dialog Fragment.when listviews are gone ,DF display in a small window.once they are displaying the screen is re sizing..